# Davinci Resolve 12 (Editing)

Tags: editing, canon, avchd, davinci-resolve

So, Im starting a project in Davinci Resolve 12 (DR12) but I am used to using FCPX and they way I can change the Field Dominance for the clips as I use a Canon C100 which records in 25p (50i) AVCHD, but playing back it is not in progressive format. In FCPX I can just select all the clips and change the field dominance in the inspector, now I cannot find out how to do this in DR12 or am I just being over ambitious?

Can anyone help or advise.

EDIT

Images below

DR12 Clip Properties - no option to change the clip to PROGRESSIVE like in FCPX

DR12 clip in timeline =- Notice the lines / interlacing

[image: DR12 Clip Properties - no option to change the clip to PROGRESSIVE like in FCPX]

[image: DR12 clip in timeline =- Notice the lines / interlacing]

EDIT 2

Added FCPX images

[image: DR12 media window]

EDIT 3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Media View window, select all the clips you want to change.  Right click one of the selected clips and choose "Clip Attributes".  In the Video portion of the Clip Attributes, tell Resolve what you want it to do.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it doesn't work, I have some screenshots if thats any help

Comment: Go ahead and post the screenshots.  What Clip Attributes are default for your clips?  What Clip Attributes have you attempted to override?

Comment: added screenshots to the main question

Comment: You did not answer the question with respect to Clip Attributes.

Comment: Hi. I thought that's what the screenshots are of. Is there a different section. If so how do I get to them ?

Comment: In the Media View window, not the Edit Window, select a clip, right-click the clip, and choose "Clip Attributes" from the dialog box that appears.

Comment: I still don't see a "Progressive" option in the clip attributes in the media window, am I missing something really simple

Comment: Is that option - "Field Dominance" context sensitive i.e. do the same choices appear with a known progressive clip?